# How can a RecyclerView adapter display multiple different GraphView graphs?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-graphview

I want to display live graphs of incoming bluetooth sensor data in a list of cards.

I have tried using the `AppendData()` function for each series that holds data for the the various sensors. The series are stored in a list.

I first initialize the list of series with some series containing dummy data:

```
private List<PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint>> dataSeriesList = Arrays.asList(initSeries, initSeries, initSeries, initSeries, initSeries, initSeries);
```

Then, in `onBindViewHolder()` I update each of the series with the new reading:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductCardViewHolder holder, int position) {

  ....

 dataSeriesList.get(position).appendData(newReading, true, 40);

....

//I set the series to the GraphView just once, like so:
 if (holder.graph.getSeries().size() == 0)
            holder.graph.addSeries(dataSeriesList.get(position));

...
}
```

I would expect that I would have 6 different graphs that each display the values for one sensor, since I am appending to a different series in the list for each `position`.

Instead, what I get are 6 identical graphs that display all 6 of the different sensor values for each point on the x-axis.

I have confirmed using logcat that each graph is only displaying one series, this means that each series somehow contains all of the data. I don't understand why, since I am clearly appending my readings to 6 seperate series.

Comment: When the data comes in, is it possible that onBindViewHolder is called for each position with each data point?

Comment: no, i know this because i am able to display the current value of all the incoming sensors at the same time in their corresponding cards

Comment: It's not an area I have done complex work in, but in the code assigning the series to the card, what makes sure that on start up (when everything, bot the graphs and the data series are of zero length) each data series is only uniquely assigned to one graph?